# integrating ZBarSdk readertest example into an existing app

Tags: iphone, ios, zbar-sdk

I am trying to include the Zbarsdk in my existing app...I found readertest example really a good example as it includes all features and option however the example includes only .m file named "reader test.m" which has AppDelegate embeded into it...It does not have xib too as all initialization made programatically...so how could I add it to my app which has an option to scans the code?

Answer (score 0):

Import ZBarSDK folder which should have a libzbar.a library and header files and resources files.

Now use ZBarReaderDelegate after importing "ZBarReaderController.h" file and use the following functions:

```
   -(IBAction) scan
    {    
        NSLog(@" SCAN BARCODE BUTTON TAPPED ");
        ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
        reader.readerDelegate = self;
        reader.showsHelpOnFail = YES;

        ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
        [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                       config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                           to: 0];

        [self presentModalViewController:reader animated:YES];
    }

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = info[ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        break;
    NSString *EANCode = symbol.data;

    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

  // so you have got the EAN code as result use it in your app
}
```

Comment: @Bhupendra....I want my view look alike the reader test example of ZBarSdk...have you checked it?

Comment: then what else you want to do ?

Comment: https://github.com/arciem/ZBarSDK/tree/master/Examples/readertest

Download the example and check its looks and option list. I want it to incorporate the same to my app and want it to open when my user click on "Scan" button....The implementation of the project depends upon one file reader test.m which has class declaration, app delegate implementation, UI initialization everything.